# Python 3 Subprocess does not terminate with signal.SIGINT

Tags: python-3.x

I've read many of the questions here on SO, but none of the solutions seem to solve my problem. I have a file called "light_led.py" which looks like this

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

# Set the mode for the GPIO numbering
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
pin = 23

# Set the GPIO as output
gpio.setup(pin, gpio.OUT, initial=gpio.LOW)

try:
    while True: # Run forever
        gpio.output(pin, gpio.HIGH) # Turn on
        time.sleep(1)                  # Sleep for 1 second
        gpio.output(pin, gpio.LOW)  # Turn off
        time.sleep(1)                  # Sleep for 1 second
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # cleanup all GPIO 
    gpio.cleanup()
    print('Cleaned up')
```

It simply toggles an LED on and off. This file is called in the following script

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
import subprocess
import signal

# Set the mode for the GPIO numbering
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
pin = 24

# Set the GPIO as input w/ pull up
gpio.setup(pin, gpio.IN, pull_up_down = gpio.PUD_UP)

# Initialize
pin_prev = gpio.input(pin)

while True:
    pin = gpio.input(pin)

    if (pin == 0) and (pin_prev == 1):
         process = subprocess.Popen('python <PATH-TO-FILE>/light_led.py', shell=True)
         print('Should be blinking')

    if (pin == 1) and (pin_prev == 0):
        process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT) 
        print('Should be off')

    # Update previous state
    pin_prev = pin

    # Slight pause to debounce
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

The files run fine and do what they're suppose to. The only problem I'm having is that I can't stop the blinking light by "flipping the switch". In other words, I'm having trouble with this `process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)`. There are not errors, so I don't have much to report.

I've tried `process.terminate()` and `os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGINT)`, both with no luck. I just want to stop the subprocess from running and continue with the main toggle script. From what I read, "signal.SIGINT" should invoke the "KeyboardInterrupt" in the subprocess...but maybe not?